# search and replace text inside html of div in javascript but not text inside tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I've some HTML structure and i want to search particular text inside that HTML structure.
see below example

```
<h1>Try to span some text on this page</h1>
    <div>
        span is a <span>paragraph</span>.</div>
    <p class="span ddd">This 123is a paragraph.1</p>

<div class="span ddd">This is some span in a div element.</div>
```

Now if I'm searching for "span" text then, "span" word should be wrapped with div tag. 
But only "span" word in text and not from class or other tags.

i want output like this (wrap using div or span)

```
<h1>Try to <span class="search">span</span> some text on this page</h1> <div> <span class="search">span</span> is a <span>paragraph</span>.</div> <p class="span ddd">This 123is a paragraph.1</p> <div class="span ddd">This is some <span class="search">span</span> in a div element.</div>
```

Comment: sample output please, have a habit to attach it with the main question

Comment: search variable is coming from input or you want to do yourself? posting your tried code will be helpful to answer.

Comment: `only "span" word in text`, what do you mean, there's elements wrapping everything?

Comment: i want output like this (wrap using div or span)
 <h1>Try to <span class="search">span</span>  some text on this page</h1>
    <div>
        <span class="search">span</span>  is a <span>paragraph</span>.</div>
    <p class="span ddd">This 123is a paragraph.1</p>

<div class="span ddd">This is some <span class="search">span</span>  in a div element.</div>

Comment: Please put the sample output in the question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
    <h1>Try to span some text on this page</h1>
  <div>
    span is a <span>paragraph</span>.
  </div>
    <p class="span ddd">This 123is a paragraph.1</p>

    <div class="span ddd">This is some span in a div element.</div>
</div>
```

I have modifed your html by enclosing with a wrapper for getting my selector. But you can use your own selectors.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var str=$('#wrapper').html();
   $('#wrapper').html(str.replace( new RegExp(" span ","g"),"<div>span</div>"));
});
```

This code will do what you need. 
Here is the  [jsffiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moyeen52/SZ5wN/1/) for this.

If your problem is fixed then please don't forget to mark this as solved. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the help it worked, but i got one more issue with this example is that, i also want to search span which is like "xyzspanlmn"

<h1>Try to select some text on this page</h1>
    <div>
        h_span_h is a <span>paragraph</span>.</div>
    <p>This 123is a paragraph.1</p>

<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure if this is what you want. But something like this should work

```
$(function() {
    var found = $('div:contains("span")');
});
```

Here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/z7ckK/

If you use `*:contains` it search it inside HTML.

UPDATE:
Initially missed the replace part. I have a solution, but for that you need a wrapping element over the search elements. Please check my fiddle. You will understand.
http://jsfiddle.net/z7ckK/3/

Comment: the op wants to search `span`s written inside text and replace with `<div>span</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex: `(?<!<[^>])${searchWord}(?<![^>]<)`

```
let innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML
let searchWord = 'span'
let regex = new RegEx(`(?<!<[^>])${searchWord}(?<![^>]<)`,gi)

innerHTML.replace(regex, (x)=> {
return `<div>x</div>`;
});
```